# expected value of sum of square on lack of fit test

Tags: regression, expected-value, goodness-of-fit

I am studying the part of lack of fit test on linear regression analysis.

let
$y_{ij}=\mu_j + \epsilon_{ij}$, $i=1,2,...n_j$, $j=1,2,...,k$
be the full model. ($\epsilon_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, i.i.d)

And the reduced model is 
$y_{ij}=\beta_0+\beta_1x_j + \epsilon_{ij}$, $i=1,2,...n_j$, $j=1,2,...,k$
that is, there is $n_j$ observation of $y$ for each $x_j$.

On my textbook, 
$SS_{Res}=SS_{PE}+SS_{LOF}$ and
$SS_{PE}$ is given by
$ \sum_{j=1}^{k} n_j(\bar y_j - \hat y_j)^2$.

and

$ E(SS_{PE})$=$\sigma^2+\Large\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k} n_j(\mu_j-\beta_0-\beta_1x_j)^2}{k-2}$.

The question is the assumption when calculating this expected value.

I don't understand where $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ came from, because in the full model, there is no $\beta$ in the model, and I think the expected value should only be a function of $y$, $x$, and $\mu$, not $\beta$.

In case of the reduced model,  $\mu_j-\beta_0-\beta_1x_j$ equals to $0$ and the second term is always $0$.

This is very confusing to me, and I wish I can get some help.

Comment: I guess full model should have $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$s and  more regressors; for instance, $y_{ij}=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{j 1} +\sum \beta_l x_{j l}+ \epsilon_{ij}$ so that $\mu_j= \beta_0+\beta_1x_{j 1} +\sum \beta_l x_{j l}$. I add more subscription to make difference of the other regressors for same observation y from the $x_1$s